# cant figure out where i went wrong with double negation query (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database

Im trying find the properties (pids) that have at least ALL the meter types as the property id 7 has. Im trying to use a double negation query but i keep getting errors, i think im very close to getting this right (im finding double negation conceptually difficult) can someone please help me find my error?

`SELECT DISTINCT pid
  FROM PROPERTYMETER X
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
      FROM PROPERTYMETER Y
       WHERE pid = 7) 
    AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT * 
        FROM PROPERTYMETER
       WHERE pid = X.pid
       AND metertype` = Y.metertype)

[PROPERTYMETER table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVtFg.png) [METERTYPE table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxw87.png)

i only used the PROPERTYMETER table but maybe there is a better way to do this by joining PROPERTYMETER and METERTYPE?

-Thanks

Comment: Please show sample data.

Comment: edited @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One conceptual way to proceed here is to inner join each `pid` group of meter values to a table consisting only of the meter values for `pid=7`.  Then aggregate by `pid` and assert that the number of distinct meter types for each `pid` group matches the number meter types for `pid=7`.

```
SELECT
    p1.pid
FROM PROPERTYMETER p1
INNER JOIN PROPERTYMETER p2
    ON p1.metertype = p2.metertype AND
       p2.pid = 7
GROUP BY
    p1.pid
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT p1.metertype) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT metertype)
                                    FROM PROPERTYMETER WHERE pid = 7)
```

**Output:**

Only `pid` 7 and 9 are returned.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester